# how to delete all sym links in SuSE LINUX in one directory recursively

Tags: linux

Can anyone help me to delete all sym soft links from the home dir and below recursively?
I have about 1000 links and don`t want to del it manually.
thanks
walter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
find ~ -type l -exec rm '{}' +
```

To ensure that's what you really want, first execute

```
find ~ -type l -print
```

to get and examine the list.

Comment: Simple and direct. I should re-learn the options on find; I have too much tendency to rely on grepping its output.